# Question about polymorph

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

For the spell polymorph, it says that you keep your alignment and personality. Does that mean when an evil character polymorphs into a t-rex, he will attack his friends and team?

Comment: related: [What kind of control should a player have over themselves when they are polymorphed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71920/23064)

Answer (score 6):

If that is how you express your personality and alignment when you are *not* polymorphed then, sure. Of course, one wonders how or why such a person would have “friends and team”.